# Proportionally fill new variable based on values in previous column?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, dplyr

I would like to create a new variable using information elsewhere in my dataframe. This seems straightforward, but I would like to assign the levels of the new variable proportionally.

I have a dataframe:

```
dd<-read.table(text="
group     piece      answer
group1     A          noise
group1     A          silence
group1     A          silence
group1     B          silence
group1     B          loud_noise
group1     B          noise
group1     B          loud_noise
group1     B          noise
group2     C          silence
group2     C          silence", header=TRUE)
```

I would like to create a new variable 'majority_annotation' with two levels: good and bad. Good means that each piece had a majority answer agreement (>55%). Bad means that the piece did not have majority answer agreement.

```
    group     piece      answer       majority_agreement
    group1     A          noise       good 
    group1     A          silence     good
    group1     A          silence     good
    group1     B          silence     bad
    group1     B          loud_noise  bad
    group1     B          noise       bad
    group1     B          loud_noise  bad
    group1     B          noise       bad
    group2     C          silence     good
    group2     C          silence     good
```

I can do this binarily (all or no agreement):

```
    newdf <- df %>% 
      group_by(group) %>% 
      mutate(majority_agreement = ifelse(length(unique(answer)) <= 1,        
    'good', 
          ifelse(length(unique(answer) > 1) & 
          (length(unique(answer)) >= 2), 'bad', 'bad'))) %>% 
      as.data.frame
```

How can I do it proportionally though?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "probabilistically" here? I don't understand what you are trying do to. What would the desired result be?

Comment: The desired result is listed in the second block of code. The answers for each 'piece' should be evaluated. If more than 55% of the answers are the same, the majority_agreement is 'good.' If less than 55% of the answers are the same, the majority_agreement is 'bad.'

Comment: OK. I see now. I don't think "probabilistically" is the right word because there are no probabilities here. I think you may just mean "proportionally"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
newdf <- df %>% 
  count(group, piece, answer) %>%   # How many of each answer for each group & piece
  group_by(group, piece) %>%
  mutate(share = n / sum(n)) %>%  # What share have this answer?
  summarize(max_share = max(share)) %>%  # What's the largest share among them?
  mutate(majority_agreement = if_else(max_share > 0.55, "good", "bad")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  right_join(df)  # Add the conclusion back to the original data
```

Comment: Thank you! Even if it's more lines of code, I like this answer because it's easier to see the steps that take place and I appreciate having the addtl variable 'max_share' as a sanity check. Also thank you for if_else - I forgot about that and was using that awful ifelse. Much more elegant your way.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do what you want using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% 
  group_by(piece) %>% 
  mutate(majority_agreement = if_else(max(table(answer)/n())>.55, "good", "bad"))
```

Within each "piece", we use `table()` to count the number of different responses and divide that by `n()` to get the proportion for each of those responses. We look if the max proportion is greater than .55. If it is, we give the label "good", otherwise we give the label "bad"